# Google Chrome Extensions: create a window only once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm opening a new window by clicking on the extension button near the search bar.
I'd like to open a new window only if it's not already opened; in that case, I'd prefer showing the old one.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
  var v = null;
  var vid = null;
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.windows.getAll({}, function(list) {
      // check if already exists
      for(window in window_list)
        if(window.id == vid) { window.focus(); return; }

      chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w) {
        v = chrome.windows.create({'url': 'my_url', 'type': 'panel', 'focused': true});
        vid = w.id;
      });
    });
  });
```

Can someone explain me how to fix it?

Most probably, both `v` and `vid` values are deleted after closing the app (after it finish to execute the script), but how can I fix it? If possible, without using localStorage or cookies.

I've tried specifying the `tabId` properties while creating the window, but it doesn't work.
I've also tried using the `chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener` functionality, but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Change `window` to **another** variable name.
2. Be consistent in variable names. `window_list` and `list` are different things.
3. Use [`chrome.windows.update`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-update) instead of `window.focus()`, because the latter does not work.
4. Use [`chrome.windows.get`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-get) to see whether the window exists, instead of maintaining a list of windows.
5. The details of the new window are available in the callback of [`chrome.windows.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create). Use this method in the correct way:

Code:

```
chrome.windows.get(vid, function(chromeWindow) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError && chromeWindow) {
        chrome.windows.update(vid, {focused: true});
        return;
    }
    chrome.windows.create(
        {'url': 'my_url', 'type': 'panel', 'focused': true},
        function(chromeWindow) {
            vid = chromeWindow.id;
        }
    );
});
```

Or, instead of checking whether the window exists, just update the window, and when an error occurs, open a new one:

```
chrome.windows.update(vid, {focused: true}, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        chrome.windows.create(
            {'url': 'my_url', 'type': 'panel', 'focused': true},
            function(chromeWindow) {
                vid = chromeWindow.id;
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: @auino Your whole code was broken, I have updated my answer, and expanded "// Rest of code"

Comment: Hey. I got one bug in there. instead of for( in ) use simple for loop. It takes index number as id sometimes.
    for(j=0; j<window_list.length; j++) {

Answer (score -1):

```
chrome.windows.getAll({}, function(window_list) {
    var extWindow = '';
    window_list.forEach(function(chromeWindow) {
        //Check windows by type
        if (chromeWindow.type == 'panel') {
            extWindow = chromeWindow.id;
            //Update opened window
            chrome.windows.update(extWindow, {focused: true});
            return;
        }
    });

    if (extWindow == '') {
        //Open window
        chrome.windows.create(
            {
                'url'       : 'my_url',
                'type'      : 'panel',
                'focused'   : true
            },
            function(chromeWindow) {
                extWindow = chromeWindow.id;
            }
        );
    }
});
```

It is an alternative code that works for me

Comment: Can you provide a better explanation of this fix?

Comment: It's best to explain your code, how it's different from "wrong" code in the question. Just a couple of comments is probably not enough. Especially since there already is a very similar accepted answer - how is yours different and why/when it's better? However, I disagree with the downvote - it's not useless.

Comment: Actually, I might reconsider. Unless a specific experimental flag is set, I don't think windows opened this way retain type `"panel"`.